# New Boston GUI - compilation error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors

I have made the following basic GUI program in Java using Swing. I got it from the new Boston's first Java GUI tutorials. I have checked and the code is exactly the same but I always get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at gui.gui_1.main(gui_1.java:4)
```

Here is my code:

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class gui_1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String fn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter first number");
            String sn =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter second number");

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(fn);
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sn);

            int sum = num1 + num2;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the answer is "+ sum, "the title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
}
```

Comment: please tell me if you have seen this qeustion but cant answer it in comments

Comment: Your code is correct. How is compiled your project?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is you have created this class under the package named - 'gui' but have missed to add that as the first line in your java file. The very first line should be the package under which your class/java file resides/created.Adding the following line at the top of your file should resolve the issue -

```
package gui;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip it worked and now I am able to proceed in have gui proggraming.

Comment: Accept the answer if it resolved your issue, it helps when someone else lands up in same kind off problem.